# Why does my function/algorithm print out the output twice?

Tags: python, algorithm

I tried to make a basic algorithm and it works however, the sum and average print out twice, and the small and largest digit sometimes prints twice or doesn't print.

```
revenues_list = []
answer = input("Do you have data to record? ")

while (answer != "no"):
  try:
    earnings = float(input("How much was earned? "))
  except:
    print("You need to give a number with digits.")
  answer = input("Do you have more data to record? ")
  revenues_list.append(earnings)

print(revenues_list)

#make a function that finds the maximun value of the list
def getMaximun(L):
   myMaximun= L[0]
   for element in revenues_list:
    if(myMaximun > element):
      myMaximun = element
      print("Your largest element is: " + str(myMaximun))
#make a function that finds the minimun value of the list
def getMinimun(L):
  myMinimun= L[0]
  for element in revenues_list:
    if(myMinimun < element):
      myMinimun = element
      print("Your smallest element is: " + str(myMinimun))
#make a function that finds the average of the list
def getAverage(L):
  sum = 0
  for element in revenues_list: 
    sum = sum + element
    average = sum/len(L)
    print("Your sum revenue is: " + str(sum) + "\n" + "Your average revenue is: " + str(average))
getMaximun(revenues_list)
getMinimun(revenues_list)
getAverage(revenues_list)
```

Comment: Note that the `print` is in the loop ...

Comment: Side comment: in general, and except for debug purposes, functions that _compute_ something should not _print_ anything. I advise you to switch your way of writing those functions (that is usual at least when starting coding), by using `return` and _return_ the value to the caller. So, at the end of each `get...` function, use `return myResult` instead of `print(myresult)` (at the correct location, see existing answer), and where you call the function use `print(getXxx(revenues_list))`, or use an intermediary if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I will pick one of the examples. As noted in the comment from @Damien you have to move the print statement out of the `for` loop, so e.g. like this:

```
for element in revenues_list:
    if(element > myMaximun):
        myMaximun = element
print("Your largest element is: " + str(myMaximun))
```

Side Note:
For asking such a question it is a good idea to make a minimal working example. Read this [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Using this approach can also often help in debugging/solving the problem before actually needing StackOverflow.

Comment: That code snippet would actually compute the minimum, not the maximum!

Comment: That is correct, I just copied it from the question. I will edit.